# Liquid that burns in a vacuum

Tags: materials

This may seem like a silly question, but is there a flammable liquid that could oxidise itself, so it could effectively burn in a vacuum?

Comment: Rocket propellants, which are generally mixtures of fuel and oxidiser

Comment: Nitroglycerine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed yes, and it's been used in all kinds of airless situations, including torpedos and rockets and I think even submarines.  It's hydrogen peroxide, which when exposed to a catalyst will oxidize and reduce itself:

2 H2O2(l) -> 2 H2O(g) + O2(g)

You'll notice that the oxygens on the left are in oxidation state -1.  Half of them become reduced to the O in water (oxidation state -2) and half become oxidized to the O in O2 (oxidation state 0).

Comment: thanks, could the concentration be 12% or less, as UK laws prohibit me from owning hydrogen peroxide  in a concentration greater than 12%?

Comment: Nope.  And those laws were probably passed specifically for the purpose of keeping rocket propellant out of your hands!  If you'll settle for vicarious living, I've heard this book https://www.amazon.com/Ignition-Informal-History-Liquid-Propellants-ebook/dp/B076838QS2/ is a whole lot of fun.